# Using Terminal, how can I find which directory is my USB drive mounted in?

Tags: terminal, usb, folders

I am using Terminal and have looked through directories.

I just can't find where my USB drive its directory is.

Which directory is my USB drive mounted in?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

All drives (internal, external and networked) get mounted in `/Volumes`. You should see a folder there with the name of your USB drive as it appears on your desktop or in the Finder.

Comment: More generally, you can use the `mount` command to see all the mounted volumes and where they are mounted. (Only a subset are mounted in /Volumes.)

Comment: AFAIK both external storage devices and .dmg files are mounted in `/Volumes`, at least by default. What other subset are you referring to here?

Comment: You can also drag&drop the usb drive from the Finder to the Terminal to get its path ;-)

Comment: I plugged in a USB drive and did `ls /Volumes` and a new folder had popped up for my USB thumb drive called `NO NAME`. That's the one for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

Some techniques to try:

```
ls -a /Volumes
```

or...

```
ls -l /Volumes
```

or...

```
ls -la /Volumes
```

...may prove useful.

```
mount
```

seems to give all the partitions that might be useful with Disk Utility, during formatting, etc.

you can probably reach your USB drive directly using:

```
/Volumes/<NameOfYourDrive>
```

This applies to other types of drives as well: optical, internal and external hard drives.  All mounted volumes.

Comment: Strange how you can't right-click on the Finder-view icons or even the desktop-icon for additional properties including the file-paths for external media-drives connected to a device running macOS Catalina; you can access file-folder paths and other properties from said locations in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 14):

In general, to find where something is mounted, you can run this command from the terminal:

```
df -H
```

This also provides useful information about the space on the drive.

Comment: After I plugged in my USB thumb drive, my `df -h` showed a new entry at the very bottom, with a mount point of `/Volumes/NO NAME`. That's my USB drive I just plugged in!

Answer (score 5):

1. I like to use three native utilities all in one go, just to be thorough and get all the details.

**in:**

```
diskutil list; df -Hl; echo; mount
```

**out:**

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            499.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   499G   490G   8.9G    99% 2582670 4292384609    0%   /

/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)

---

2. If you don't want a lot of information, you can just check for mounted disk partitions in `/dev`:

**in:**

```
ls /dev/disk*
```

**out:**

```
/dev/disk0      /dev/disk0s1    /dev/disk0s2    /dev/disk0s3
```

---

3. To list ownership and permissions, etc :

**in:**

```
ls -alh /dev/disk*
```

**out:**

```
brw-r-----  1 root  operator    1,   0 29 Oct 11:24 /dev/disk0
brw-r-----  1 root  operator    1,   1 29 Oct 11:24 /dev/disk0s1
brw-r-----  1 root  operator    1,   3 29 Oct 11:24 /dev/disk0s2
brw-r-----  1 root  operator    1,   2 29 Oct 11:24 /dev/disk0s3
```

---

- [`diskutil`](http://ss64.com/osx/diskutil.html)
- [`df`](http://ss64.com/osx/df.html)
- [`mount`](https://ss64.com/bash/mount.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this command in terminal to get more hardware info on your USB devices

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType
```

This will produce an output like this:

```
USB 3.0 Bus:

  Host Controller Driver: AppleUSBXHCISPTLP
  PCI Device ID: 0x9d2f 
  PCI Revision ID: 0x0021 
  PCI Vendor ID: 0x8086 

    USB3.0 Hub:
      Product ID: 0x0813
      [...]

    USB2.0 Hub:

      Product ID: 0x2813
      [...]

        STORE N GO:

          Product ID: 0x0302
          [...]
          Media:
            STORE N GO:
              Capacity: 15,53 GB (15.525.216.256 bytes)
              Removable Media: Yes
              BSD Name: disk4
              Logical Unit: 0
              Partition Map Type: MBR (Master Boot Record)
              S.M.A.R.T. status: Verified
              USB Interface: 0
              Volumes:
                Install macOS Catalina:
                  Capacity: 15,5 GB (15.499.132.928 bytes)
                  Free: 7,18 GB (7.176.282.112 bytes)
                  Writable: Yes
                  File System: Journaled HFS+
                  BSD Name: disk4s1
                  Mount Point: /Volumes/Install macOS Catalina
                  Content: Apple_HFS
                  Volume UUID: 3D469C8E-1F35-341D-95A8-0B16EDE21B29

        USB 2.0 BILLBOARD             :

          Product ID: 0x0100
          [...]
```

Where you can appreciate the mounting point of your USB device:

`Mount Point: /Volumes/Install macOS Catalina` (in my case it's a Catalina OS install pendrive)

Comment: How can this command be used to solve the problem described in the question?

Comment: This is useful to developers like myself who are trying to specifically differentiate a USB thumbdrive of unknown name from other mounted volumes.  This could happen for example, in systems that can be overridden by alternate settings stored on a thumbdrive, IF the thumbdrive is present.  In this case I want to not care what the volume is named, I just want to find whatever thumbdrive(s) is present.

Comment: @nohillside if you run the command with a USB pendrive on, you will find a part where it mentiones the pendrive and the mounting point.

Comment: @mariano-daniel Explaining how this can be done might make a worthwhile edit to the answer.

Comment: @nohillside totally agree with you.

Comment: @mariano-daniel One of the great things about StackExchange sites is that everybody can edit any content. So if you see a way to improve the question please go ahead and do so.

Comment: @nohillside alright! You convinced me to do my first edit on SE, haha! Let's hope it helps. At least I tried. Thanks for the encouragement!

Comment: @mariano-daniel Great. I shortened the output a bit to make it easier to spot.

Answer (score 0):

Try lsusb.  It was given me by Erik Kaashoek; he is the designer of the **tinySA** and the **Ultra tinySA**.

The command works great as it only lists USB devices.

Comment: I have edit your answer and removed the “replies.”   This site is a Q&A site and not a threaded forum.  It might be useful to take the [tour] to familiarize yourself with how the site works.  Finally, can you [Edit] your answer with links to the utility you referenced?

Answer (score -2):

easy peezy lemon squeezy.

```
cd /volumes/whatever-the-name-of-volume
```

if that doesn't work then do it step by step

cd /volume and then cd into whatever the name is of the device.

Comment: How does this differ from or improve on other answers?